# How to create this kind of effect? Thank you, guys

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

How to create this kind of effect? Thank you, guys[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you [edit] your question with some of your results so we can help you improve upon? It's much easier to open illustrator and try something first than coming here asking the question directly. Also not everything is a one-click effect if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of what our community is about, *then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a *good* query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question shows *some* **effort**: show us what you *already tried* and failed; document what you found when researching; as applicable, illustrate your question with sketches, screenshots or examples. We *also* have a ***strong*** preference *against* requests for step-by-step tutorials. Please read [ask] and revise your question a bit - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No single click effect, unfortunately. You must draw it.

[image]

1. A text, outlined and ungrouped, no fill, a thin stroke is inserted.
2. Draw one or more lines over the writing
3. Split the writing with the lines. Select the line, goto Object > Path > Divide Objects Below
4. Drag some parts further and scale them bigger
5. Connect the parts by drawing lines (=red) Have Smart Guides and Snap to Points ON. Te ends must be in the corner points. Fix with the direct selection tool, if needed.
6. Select all. Unite the areas with the Shape Builder (=drag over division lines). Select the wanted fill color and stroke.

Your example has second folding stage in some letters. You can add them for ex. by moving and scaling the splitted parts again before uniting with the shape builder. Then you can draw new set of connection lines.

Actually no connection lines are needed. Insert new nodes to the outlined letters and simply stretch them with the direct selection tool. Select only for ex the lower part. Then you can scale with Object > Transform > Scale:

[image]

The scaled area is selected with the direct selection tool. Curved parts unfortunately are difficult to control. With connection lines there's no curved parts.

Comment: Thank you! Was hoping for 2 click effect))

Comment: A programmer could create it. But that job can take 10000 clicks before the effect is ready to use.